# Git repository clone always import the same project

Tags: eclipse, git, github

**Edit: I found out what is causing the problem. I've added a new remote/origin/ entry in the git config that's causing eclipse to fetch the same project everytime.**

I am new to git. I am having some problem with cloning a repo into eclipse.

No matter which repo I try to clone, the "Import project from Git" screen always force me to select the same project name(in this case it's membership program) and when I click the finish button. It always import "membership program" into eclipse.

Here is a link ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePc5v.jpg )  containing the screenshots of the import process so you can get a better idea of what I am talking about.

Anyone have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: If you fixed your own problem, add your solution as an answer to the question and accept it, so the question doesn't show up as "unanswered" any more, and to help other users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try selecting the 'new project' radio button on the second dialog in your screenshot.